# Why iterm2 keyboard shortcut settings don't work on window launched using F12

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, iterm

I've followed the instructions [here](https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda/use-and-to-jump-backwards-words-in-iterm-2-on-os-x) on how to make <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> skip words backward and forward..

this works just fine on the original window displayed by iterm2.. however when i press <kbd>F12</kbd> and the window shows up.. those keyboard shortcuts don't work any more.. any idea why and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Preferences Window of iTerm choose *keys* and below on the left side you see the *Hotkey Configuration*. Choose your profile from the option **Hotkey toggles a dedicated window with profile**. And this should work.

[image]